# neo4j rest api uniqueness not working?

Tags: node.js, indexing, neo4j

I'm trying to create an unique node in neo4j, but can't make it work.

node code:

```
var node = db.createNode({sampleDataKey: "sampleDataValue"});

node.save(function (err, user) {

    node.index('user', 'indexValue', 'indexValue', function (err) {
        if (err) console.log(err);
        console.log(user.id);
    });
});
```

I'm using this node module: https://github.com/thingdom/node-neo4j

I have modified the Node.js from the neo4j lib. to:

```
else {

                                  var urlToPost = ((("" + services.node_index) + "/") + index + '?uniqueness=create_or_fail');
                                  console.log(urlToPost);
                                  console.log(key + ':' + value);

/*   123 */                       return __this._request.post({
/*   124 */                         url: urlToPost,

/*   125 */                         json: {
/*   126 */                           key: key,
/*   127 */                           value: value,
/*   128 */                           uri: __this.self
                                    }
                                  }, __cb(_, __frame, 17, 21, function ___(__0, __4) {
/*   123 */                         response = __4;
                                    console.log('response');
                                    __then();
                                  }, true));
                                }
```

Each time i execute the code a new new node is created, but after that errors. ...
Here is the console log for 2 executions:

```
30 May 16:51:24 - [nodemon] starting `node app.js`
Express server listening on port 3000
http://localhost:7474/db/data/index/node/user?uniqueness=create_or_fail
indexValue:indexValue
response
338
30 May 16:55:38 - [nodemon] restarting due to changes...
30 May 16:55:38 - [nodemon] /Users/nikolaialeksandrenko/Documents/work/noject/app.js


30 May 16:55:38 - [nodemon] starting `node app.js`
Express server listening on port 3000
http://localhost:7474/db/data/index/node/user?uniqueness=create_or_fail
indexValue:indexValue
response
339
```

Comment: hi Aleksandrenko do you mean it works the first time but not the second or subsequent times?

Comment: Yes. The first time works correct, after that it does not ...

Comment: okay am not sure just trying to clarify. when you say it works the first time -> can you see the object key in the data base -> is it random or the same sample value?

Comment: It is the same node, same data, same index, just different id ...

Comment: I reset the db and execute 2 times so ... i have this:
neo4j-sh (0)$ START node = node(*)
> return node;
==> +------------------------------------------+
==> | node                                     |
==> +------------------------------------------+
==> | Node[0]{}                                |
==> | Node[1]{sampleDataKey:"sampleDataValue"} |
==> | Node[2]{sampleDataKey:"sampleDataValue"} |
==> +------------------------------------------+
==> 3 rows
==> 1 ms

Comment: I'm not able to help you more right now but i hope someone else can. what you can try as a work around is to just make your own unique key - might not be a good solution for production but for now - just give it a your IP + port without the dots + time + random number ?

Comment: or just a random number for dev testing :)

Comment: i think i was doing that :)
node.index('user', 'indexValue', 'indexValue'); ?

Comment: I think i figure it out.
I was using neo4j 1.8.2, just now i moved to 1.9 and the code work like i should. I suppose the ?uniqueness=create_or_fail is for 1.9 and up ...

Comment: you should write that as an answer and choose it as the correct answer. will help others

Comment: will do, just have to wait a day :)
(stackoverflow restrictions)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is from the version i was using (1.8.2) the optional '?uniqueness=create_or_fail'
work just fine in neo4j 1.9. The only think i have to do was to update to the newer version.